# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'

Tags: angular

I'm stuck.
I get the error in the title. In html it displays the messageBundle object and it has full data (so no missing data). Data is fetched async and that part is working, i get correct data and can display it, but i cannot loop over it. as far as i know the syntax is correct for the loop because it's working on other components which are nearly identical. app.module has BrowserModule, on child component i tried adding both CommonModule and BrowserModule with no difference. By all accounts this should work but it doesnt.
How do i fix it?

component.html:

```
<div class = "contactList">
        <p>Contacts</p>
        <div >
            <div>{{messageBundle.contacts[0]}}</div>
            <li *ngFor="let contact of messageBundle.contacts">
                <span>{{contact.full_name}}</span>
            </li>
        </div>
    </div>
```

component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from "@angular/core";
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { MessagingService } from '../message.service';
import { MessageBundle } from '../message-bundle.model';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';//does nothing

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message',
  templateUrl: './message.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message.component.css']
})
export class MessageComponent    {
  private messageBundleListener:Subscription;
  public messageBundle : MessageBundle;

  constructor(private messageService : MessagingService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.messageBundle  = this.messageService.getMessageBundle();
    this.messageService.fetch_entire_message_bundle_from_backend_server();
    console.log("updated budnle on component on start"+this.messageBundle);
    this.messageBundleListener = this.messageService.getMessageBundleUpdateListenerAsObservable().subscribe(
      (updatedMessageBundle)=>{
        this.messageBundle= updatedMessageBundle;//gets correct data, data is all there
        console.log("updated bundle on message component");
        console.dir(this.messageBundle)
      }
    );
  }
  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.messageBundleListener.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

app.module.ts :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...
import { MessageComponent } from './messages/message-window/message.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
   ...
    MessageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
      ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You imported `common`-module ?

Comment: import CommonMdoule

Comment: @Sajad  CommonModule is already a part of Browser module. I believe the problem wa in my IDE, it was solved as soon as i hit post on the question. (i wish it was a minute of two sooner..)

Comment: ng serve could also cause this problem i believe

Answer (score 1):

There is no syntax error.
I spent an hour on this, changed ngFor to NgFor so it threw an actual error, changed it back and now it's working.
(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻